# Dynamic Point Cloud

Tags: javascript

I have another issue regarding the Image Paths on the sidebar.

I am working on a site that has to be able to load a cloud by selecting it from a grid, then selecting another cloud from the grid and:

1. Clear the existing cloud and annotations if there are any.
2. Load the new cloud with new annotations.

I have both of those two steps working. The problem I have is When I try to use the sidebar menu, Most of the information/links and Icons are gone.
I am doing things a little bit unconventional. I am using a single .aspx page to load whichever cloud is selected from the grid and not a single .html page for each cloud created. The folder structure for the libs are as follows in relation to the .aspx page

/scripts/Potree/libs

I'm fairly sure this is a path thing since everything else is working as expected. I can not figure out how to resolve this. has anyone else tried this and if so, how did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

There was a different version of JQuery loaded from the Master page of this project that conflicted with the version Potree needed. I changed the Master to only load the conflicting JQuery file if the page is not the one containing the point cloud.